# WindowsIdentity Token in Legacy ASP

Tags: c#, .net, security, com, interop

I've created a .Net library at work that is used by all of our developers. The security part of it uses Microsoft AzMan for the security backend. In order to create a security (AzMan) ClientContext I have to pass it a token value (as a uint). This is all fine an dandy until I needed to make a COM wrapper for our common library so some of our legacy pages could take advantage of it without being rewritten for now.

I cannot figure out how to get the token value to pass to AzMan from legacy ASP. The COM wrapper is setup to run as a COM Server and runs as a specific  user that we use here for all COM objects, therefor the common library can't just pull the identity using .Net.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your not able to get to token, you could always use the **IAzApplication.InitializeClientContextFromName** while retrieving the user name from the request in your asp page and passing it to your com+ component.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377363(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you using anonymous logons in the IIS configuration? If you use Windows Authentication and do the following in classic ASP you should get the logged on user:

```
Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
```

Comment: It's Windows authentication, but I need the Token like you can get from System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

In classic ASP you have to get the token from an external COM object.

It has been a long time since I have dealt with classic ASP... but someone on here who has dealt with impersonation in classic ASP might have some code snippet that they can share.